# How to pre process a class data (with a large number of unique values) before feeding it to machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, one-hot-encoding

Let's say I have a large data from an online gaming platform (like steam) which has 'date, user_id, number_of_hours_played, no_of_games' and I have to write a model to predict how many hours a user will play in future for a given date. Now, user_id has a large number of unique values (in millions). I know for class data we can use one hot encoding, but not sure what to do when I have millions of unique classes. Also, suggest if we can use any other method to preprocess the data.

Comment: What have you tried already? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I do not know what to use to embed a large number of classes. How will the one hot encoder work in this case? 
A friend of mine tried one hot encoder for 20k classes and he got some error when he used scikit learn. Error was related to size. @Arcath

Answer (score 0):

Using directly the user id in the model is not a good idea, since that would result like you said into a large number of features, but also in overfitting since you would get one id per line (If I understood correctly your data). It would also make your model useless in case of a new user id and you would have to retrain your model each time you have a new user.

What I would recommand in the first place is to drop this variable and try to build a model with only the other variables.

Another Idea that you could try is to perform a clustering on the users you have based on other features, and then pass the cluster as a feature instead of the user id, but I don't know if this is a good idea since I don't know the kind of data you have.

Also, you are talking about making a prediction on a given date. The data you described doesn't suggest that but if you have the number of hours per multiple dates, this is closer to a time series prediction problem, which is different from a 'classic' regression problem.